# zip files in server

Tags: c#, asp.net, zip

How can I zip (In the server) multiple files to one archive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code uses our [Rebex ZIP](http://www.rebex.net/zip.net/) and shows how to add files into the ZIP archive without using any temp file. The ZIP is then sent to the web browser.

```
// prepare MemoryStream to create ZIP archive within
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    // create new ZIP archive within prepared MemoryStream
    using (ZipArchive zip = new ZipArchive(ms))
    {            
         // add some files to ZIP archive
         zip.Add(@"c:\temp\testfile.txt");
         zip.Add(@"c:\temp\innerfile.txt", @"\subfolder");

         // clear response stream and set the response header and content type
         Response.Clear();
         Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
         Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "filename=sample.zip");

         // write content of the MemoryStream (created ZIP archive) 
         // to the response stream
         ms.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
    }
}

// close the current HTTP response and stop executing this page
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

For more info see [ZIP tutorial](http://www.rebex.net/zip.net/tutorial-zip.aspx).

*Alternative solution:*

[SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/) and [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) a widely used free alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/) or [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Codeplex has Dot Net Zip http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/

You can also try `System.IO.Compression`